# How can I count the number of specific files within a date range on the command line using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, date, count, grep

The request is just a basic count of files in specific directories.  My current process using `ipswitch`:

1. Copy files from the month of March to my local directory (Windows)
2. Sort by name and, if necessary, delete files I do not need to count (from my local)
3. Select all or specific files, view the total, and enter it into a spreadsheet I maintain.

The spreadsheet is for monthly reporting on deliverable...

I know some unix/linux basics like directory navigation, somewhat about grep, and almost nothing about find.

I can't figure out how to search a directory for files within a specific date range, by month, and count how many files... sometimes with specific names or extensions.  I thought

```
ls -l |grep ...something something...
```

might work, but I've hit a wall.

Let me know if more info is needed, sorry so wordy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` to filter and `wc` to count.

```
find . -mtime -$start -mtime +$end | wc -l
```

Because of the way -mtime truncates, and the exclusive nature of the comparison, it's a little tricky at first to get right, but doable.

```
find /some/path -mtime +0  # Find files modified prior to 1 day ago.
find /some/path -mtime -0  # Find files modified after 1 day ago.
find /some/path -mtime +1 -mtime -6 # Files modified between 2 and 7 days ago.
```

For example, say it's April 2, and you want all of March.  Your $start would be `31`, and your $end would be `0`.

To run the same report on April 13, your $start would be `42` and your $end would be `13`.

Comment: Is the dot for current directory?

Comment: Yes, and you could give a fixed path if you prefer.

Comment: I still don't quite understand how to apply this to my predicament... I'll check back tomorrow and provide more info.

Comment: Perfect, this should get me to where I'm going, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `-newerXY` option to `find` to search for files within (and below) a directory between two dates directly. The date format can include a time with fidelity down to the second (e.g. `"2017-04-13 21:35:58"` or generically `"yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s"`)

The generic form of the option is `-newerXY` where `XY` can be one of `a` access time, `B` birth time, `c` inode status change time `m` modification time and `t` interpreted directly as time.

To search between two given dates (say for November 2016), you can use a form of `find` similar to:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -newermt "2016-10-30 23:59:59" \
! -newermt "2016-12-01 00:00:00"
```

That will list all files between the end of October 2016 and the beginning of December 2016 (e.g. all files modified in November 2016), where

- `-type f` limits the find to 'files' not 'files & directories'
- `-newermt "2016-10-30 23:59:59"` files modified after the last second in October
- `! -newermt "2016-12-01 00:00:00"` and not modified after the last second in November

Of course the `'\'` is simply a line continuation character used to split the line between the date tests so it doesn't generate a horizontal scroll-bar in this answer -- you can omit it and put everything on one line.

If you need to count the files, just pipe the output to `wc -l` as phatfingers shows in his earlier answer. An easy way to date-sort the files is simply to use `find` in *command substitution* as the argument to `ls -t` (along with any other options to `ls` you may desire), e.g.:

```
$ ls -lrt $(find . -newermt 2016-10-30 ! -newermt 2016-12-01)
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 3180 Nov  9 13:02 ./inventory2.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  769 Nov 19 23:00 ./xfree.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 1375 Nov 20 16:14 ./reallocprob.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david   98 Nov 21 00:39 ./hw.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  530 Nov 25 23:10 ./tools2/tools.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 1175 Nov 25 23:15 ./tools2/main.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  174 Nov 25 23:16 ./tools2/tools.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  424 Nov 26 00:28 ./tools/tsave.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  106 Nov 26 01:34 ./tools/tools.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  909 Nov 26 01:53 ./tools/main.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  525 Nov 26 02:45 ./tools/tools.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 1732 Nov 27 23:53 ./nogets.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  530 Nov 30 22:17 ./resolution.c
```